# Yii2 Optional textbox with Checkbox from database

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist

I am using following code to generate checkboxes from database. I need to add optional textbox for some options. Can anybody give me clue to add it ?

```
$form->field($model_detail, 'DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID')
       ->checkboxList(
        $listData,array('separator'=>'<BR />')
       )->label('Select Document(s)');
```

Comment: What do you mean by optional text-box ?

Comment: like if you do not have option in check box then please specify and like you  you need any document of dated 26th jan 2016 then specify.

Comment: So as per my understanding, if there are 2 options given under the check-box of hobbies 1) Playing Game 2) Listening Music but my hobby is **Traveling** then I can enter the word **Travelling** in a text-box.

What I understood is same as your requirement ?

Comment: yes some thing like that if 3rd option is other and if user checks it then text box should appear so that he/she can enter Traveling.

Comment: You need to use jQuery to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extends `ActiveField` and write your custom `checkboxList` method. It may looks like this:

```
class ProjectActiveField extends ActiveField
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function checkboxList($items, $options = [])
    {
        $inputs = '';
        foreach ($items as $id => $value) {
            $input = Html::activeCheckbox($this->model, $this->$id, $options);
            $description = $options['itemDescriptions'][$id];
            if ($description) {
                $input = '<div class="checkbox">' . $description . $input . '</div>';
            }

            $inputs .= $input;
        }

        $this->adjustLabelFor($options);
        $this->parts['{input}'] = $inputs;

        return $this;
    }
}
```