# Yii2 dynamic checkbox list with textbox

Tags: checkbox, yii2, textbox

I need to two textbox with checkbox. From this code i am only able to generate dynamic checkbox list. Can anybody provide me hints to achieve this ?

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($modelFixedTaskTime, "code_id")
    ->inline(false)->checkboxList($data);
?>
```

I have also tried this link but unable to solve my issue.

[Yii2 Optional textbox with Checkbox from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992552/yii2-optional-textbox-with-checkbox-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your `$data`, you can add an array of `options` to it after the `items` as fourth attribute contained single `item` formatting like this:

```php
[
    'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        return Html::checkbox($name, $checked) . Html::textInput($name, $label);
    }
]
```

Of course you need proper setup of name and value of the `textInput`.